# Time comparison between Coarse-grained and Fine-grained linked list

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, linked-list

I was studying concurrent data structures and tried to implement a linked list for fine-grained and coarse-grained cases to compare the time.

However, contrary to my expectations, the fine-grained case performed worse. I was wondering if it was all due to the overhead or if I implemented it incorrectly.

This is coarse-grained linked list.

```cpp
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;

    Node(int k) : data(k), next(nullptr) {}
};

class LinkedList {
private:
    Node* head;
    mutex lock;

public:
    LinkedList() : head(nullptr) {}

    void insert_node(int data) {
        Node* new_node = new Node(data);
        
        lock.lock();
        if(head == nullptr) {
            head = new_node;
        } else if(head->data >= data) {
            new_node->next = head;
            head = new_node;
        }
        else {
            Node* prev = nullptr;
            Node* curr = head;

            while(curr != nullptr and data > curr->data) {
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            prev->next = new_node;
            new_node->next = curr;
        }
        lock.unlock();
    }

    void delete_node(int data) {
        Node* prev = nullptr;

        lock.lock();
        Node* curr = head;
        while(curr != nullptr) {
            if(curr->data == data) {
                if(prev == nullptr)
                    head = curr->next;
                else
                    prev->next = curr->next;

                delete curr;
                break;
            }

            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        lock.unlock();
    }
```

This is fine-grained linked list.

```cpp
struct HOHNode {
    int data;
    HOHNode* next;
    mutex node_lock;

    HOHNode(int k) : data(k), next(nullptr) {}
};

class HOHLinkedList {
private:
    HOHNode* head;
    mutex list_lock;
public:
    HOHLinkedList() : head(nullptr) {}

    void insert_node(int data) {
        HOHNode* new_node = new HOHNode(data);
        
        list_lock.lock();
        if(head == nullptr or head->data >= data) {
            if(head != nullptr)
                head->node_lock.lock();
            new_node->next = head;
            head = new_node;
            list_lock.unlock();
            if(new_node->next != nullptr)
                new_node->next->node_lock.unlock();
        }
        else {
            HOHNode* prev = head;
            HOHNode* curr = head->next;

            prev->node_lock.lock();
            list_lock.unlock();
            if(curr != nullptr)
                curr->node_lock.lock();
            
            while(curr != nullptr and data > curr->data) {
                HOHNode* temp = prev;
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
                temp->node_lock.unlock();
                if(curr != nullptr)
                    curr->node_lock.lock();
            }

            new_node->next = curr;
            prev->next = new_node;
            prev->node_lock.unlock();
            if(curr != nullptr)
                curr->node_lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    void delete_node(int data) {
        list_lock.lock();
        HOHNode* prev = head;
        prev->node_lock.lock();
        if(prev->data == data) {
            head = prev->next;
            delete prev;
            list_lock.unlock();
        } else {
            HOHNode* curr = head->next;
            list_lock.unlock();
            if(curr != nullptr) {
                curr->node_lock.lock();
            }
            
            while(curr != nullptr and data >= curr->data) {
                if(curr->data == data) {
                    prev->next = curr->next;
                    delete curr;
                    prev->node_lock.unlock();
                    return;
                }

                HOHNode* temp = prev;
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
                temp->node_lock.unlock();
                curr->node_lock.lock();
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the result tested with shuffled 1 to 1000 insert and shuffled 1 to 1000 delete.

[image: Time Comparison]

---

[Editted]
Thank you for your advice. This is full code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
// #include "matplotlibcpp.h"


using namespace std;
// namespace plt = matplotlibcpp;

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;

    Node(int k) : data(k), next(nullptr) {}
};

class LinkedList {
private:
    Node* head;
    mutex lock;

public:
    LinkedList() : head(nullptr) {}

    void insert_node(int data) {
        Node* new_node = new Node(data);
        
        lock.lock();
        if(head == nullptr) {
            head = new_node;
        } else if(head->data >= data) {
            new_node->next = head;
            head = new_node;
        }
        else {
            Node* prev = nullptr;
            Node* curr = head;

            while(curr != nullptr and data > curr->data) {
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            prev->next = new_node;
            new_node->next = curr;
        }
        lock.unlock();
    }

    void delete_node(int data) {
        Node* prev = nullptr;

        lock.lock();
        Node* curr = head;
        while(curr != nullptr) {
            if(curr->data == data) {
                if(prev == nullptr)
                    head = curr->next;
                else
                    prev->next = curr->next;

                delete curr;
                break;
            }

            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        lock.unlock();
    }

    void print() {
        lock.lock();
        Node* curr = head;

        while(curr != nullptr) {
            cout << curr->data << " ";
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
        lock.unlock();
    }

    void free() {
        lock.lock();
        while(head != nullptr) {
            Node* temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;
        }
        lock.unlock();
    }
};

struct HOHNode {
    int data;
    HOHNode* next;
    mutex node_lock;

    HOHNode(int k) : data(k), next(nullptr) {}
};

class HOHLinkedList {
private:
    HOHNode* head;
    mutex list_lock;
public:
    HOHLinkedList() : head(nullptr) {}

    void insert_node(int data) {
        HOHNode* new_node = new HOHNode(data);
        
        list_lock.lock();
        if(head == nullptr or head->data >= data) {
            if(head != nullptr)
                head->node_lock.lock();
            new_node->next = head;
            head = new_node;
            list_lock.unlock();
            if(new_node->next != nullptr)
                new_node->next->node_lock.unlock();
        }
        else {
            HOHNode* prev = head;
            HOHNode* curr = head->next;

            prev->node_lock.lock();
            list_lock.unlock();
            if(curr != nullptr)
                curr->node_lock.lock();
            
            while(curr != nullptr and data > curr->data) {
                HOHNode* temp = prev;
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
                temp->node_lock.unlock();
                if(curr != nullptr)
                    curr->node_lock.lock();
            }

            new_node->next = curr;
            prev->next = new_node;
            prev->node_lock.unlock();
            if(curr != nullptr)
                curr->node_lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    void delete_node(int data) {
        list_lock.lock();
        HOHNode* prev = head;
        prev->node_lock.lock();
        if(prev->data == data) {
            head = prev->next;
            prev->node_lock.unlock(); // editted
            delete prev;
            list_lock.unlock();
        } else {
            HOHNode* curr = head->next;
            list_lock.unlock();
            if(curr != nullptr) {
                curr->node_lock.lock();
            }
            
            while(curr != nullptr and data >= curr->data) {
                if(curr->data == data) {
                    prev->next = curr->next;
                    curr->node_lock.unlock(); // editted
                    delete curr;
                    prev->node_lock.unlock();
                    return;
                }

                HOHNode* temp = prev;
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
                temp->node_lock.unlock();
                curr->node_lock.lock();
            }
        }
    }

    void print() {
        HOHNode* curr = head;
        while(curr != nullptr) {
            cout << curr->data << " ";
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    void free() {
        list_lock.lock();
        while(head != nullptr) {
            HOHNode* temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;
        }
        list_lock.unlock();
    }
};

void test_simple(LinkedList& list) {
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 rng(rd());
    
    vector<int> numbers;
    numbers.reserve(1000);
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
        numbers.push_back(i);

    shuffle(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), rng);
    for(int number : numbers)
        list.insert_node(number);
    shuffle(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), rng);
    for(int number : numbers)
        list.delete_node(number);
}

void test_HOH(HOHLinkedList& list) {
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 rng(rd());
    
    vector<int> numbers;
    numbers.reserve(1000);
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
        numbers.push_back(i);

    shuffle(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), rng);
    for(int number : numbers)
        list.insert_node(number);
    shuffle(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), rng);
    for(int number : numbers)
        list.delete_node(number);
}


int main() {
    LinkedList simple_list;
    HOHLinkedList HOH_list;
    vector<thread> list_threads;

    vector<int> x;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
        x.push_back(i);
    vector<double> simple_y;
    vector<double> HOH_y;

    for(int num_threads : x) {
        simple_list.free();
        list_threads.clear();

        auto start_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for(int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)
            list_threads.push_back(thread(test_simple, ref(simple_list)));
        for(thread& list_thread : list_threads)
            list_thread.join();
        auto end_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        chrono::duration<double> elapsed_time = end_time - start_time;
        simple_y.push_back(elapsed_time.count());

        HOH_list.free();
        list_threads.clear();

        start_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for(int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)
            list_threads.push_back(thread(test_HOH, ref(HOH_list)));
        for(thread& list_thread : list_threads)
            list_thread.join();
        end_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        elapsed_time = end_time - start_time;
        HOH_y.push_back(elapsed_time.count());
    }

    cout << "Coarse grained" << endl;
    for(double t : simple_y)
        cout << t << endl;
    cout << "Fine grained" << endl;
    for(double t : HOH_y)
        cout << t << endl;

    // plt::named_plot("Simple", x, simple_y, "x-");
    // plt::named_plot("Hand over Hand", x, HOH_y, "o-");

    // plt::title("Performance of Simple vs. Hand over Hand Linked List");
    // plt::xlabel("Threads");
    // plt::ylabel("Time (seconds)");
    // plt::xticks(x);
    // plt::legend();
    // plt::save("./linked_list.png");
}
```

Run on 4 core 8 thread with g++ 9.4.0. I didn't care about the case when trying to delete the data not exist in the list because I tested with insert 1 to 1000 and delete 1 to 1000 with only random order. I tried mixing up the order to see the benefits of the fine-grained case.

Comment: Did you also compare with `std::forward_list` and `std::vector`?

Comment: Fine-grained list has a lot more overhead. The kind of workload where this overhead might pay off is when multiple threads are working simultaneously on different parts of a long list (which may be difficult to arrange in your code, seeing as every thread has to pass through initial nodes before getting to the part it actually needs to work on). My guess is, you are not exercising a workload like that, and so are paying all that overhead for no benefit.

Comment: `HOHLinkedList::delete_node` may exhibit undefined behavior. In `if(prev->data == data) ` clause, `delete prev` is executed while `prev->node_lock` is locked. It is undefined behavior to destroy a `std::mutex` while held.

Comment: `HOHLinkedList::delete_node` leaves two nodes locked if `data` is not found anywhere in the list. This is likely to lead to a deadlock later.

Comment: Same thing in the main portion of `HOHLinkedList::delete_node`. It runs `delete cur` while `cur->node_lock` is held. This is UB.

Comment: Like I said, each thread has to traverse half the list, on average, before it can get to useful work. And all the threads are traversing *the same* half of the list, fighting over the same nodes. This is how `HOHLinkedList` adds overhead without improving concurrency - in effect, the useful work is still mostly done one thread at a time, just with way more locking and unlocking.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I thought that if one thread was moving to delete the 100th node, locking on the 50th and 51st nodes, the other threads would also be moving concurrently like locking on the 49th node to delete the node they wanted, although they could not outpacing the first thread. Did I misunderstatnding about Hand over hand locking linked list or is it simply a bad implementation?

Comment: I suspect they are stomping on each other's toes much more than you expect. Besides, you don't just need to improve concurrency - you need to improve it by enough to justify the added overhead. Locking and unlocking mutexes is not cheap - likely significantly more expensive than flipping a pointer or two. And `HOHLinkedList` is doing a lot more of the former for each of the latter.

Comment: In particular, I suspect you are observing [lock convoy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_convoy) effect. All threads queue up behind one lock. When its turn comes, a thread wakes up, performs a tiny bit of work, and queues up behind another lock. Most of the time is spent switching thread contexts.